# Change in array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I want to create a array structure with child entities like this ->

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
        "categories": [
            {
                "name": "PR",
                "sortOrder": 0,
                "type": "category"
            }

        ],
        "name": "DEPT 1",
        "sortOrder": 0,
        "type": "group",
        "id": "-JY_1unVDQ5XKTK87DjN",
        "editing": false
    }
];
```

from an array that dosen't have child entities but all the items are listed in one object like this->

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
        "name": "PR",
        "sortOrder": 0,
        "type": "category"
    },

    {
        "name": "AD",
        "sortOrder": 3,
        "type": "category"
    },
    {
        "name": "DEPT 2",
        "sortOrder": 1,
        "type": "group",
        "id": "-JYZomQKCVseJmaZoIF9",
        "editing": false,
        "categories": []
    },
];
```

Is there any possible way?

Comment: Are the `categories` associated with the `department` in some way. Or do you want to club the `categories` together in an array and the other objects as they are and ultimately encapsulate them in a single javascript object?

Comment: categories is the child of Department and I want to club them into a single object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Eagle1 has rightly pointed out. You need to define your data model properly to define a function that does that grouping for you. That said, from what I understand you have a `$scope.groups` array of objects for a specific department containing some `categories` which you need to consolidate as a child element.

You could start by defining a function that returns an object like you mention:

```
var organize = function(arr){
  cats = [];
  dep = {};
  $.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
   if(val.type == "category")
    cats.push(val);
   else
    dep = val;
  });

 dep.categories = cats;
 return dep;
}
```

Ultimately, you'll have to traverse the array and look for objects of type `category` and dump them in an array and have that array as the `categories` key of the object that you intend to return. I hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

of course it is.
It's doable in javascipt although to help you devise something we would need a relationship between categories.

However, that's sounds like something that should be done in your data model (a relationship between dept - category, classic reflexive relationship parent - children). angular should be receiving from the back end an array already ordered.

Comment: I'm getting an unordered array that contains objects without child entities.The child entities are listed with the object with difference that child entities have id of Parent object